# Increment on RobotFramework

Tags: for-loop, increment, robotframework

I'm trying to run a FOR loop on robot framework depending of the status of another variable.

```
${STATUS1}=   Run Keyword And Return Status   Should Be Equal As Strings   ${CELLVALUE}   ${EXPECTEDVALUE}
    \   ${COUNT}=   Set Variable If  '${STATUS1}' == 'True'   ${COUNT}+1
    \   ...   '${STATUS1}' == 'False'    ${COUNT}+0
```

But all I get is `'''0'+0'+0'+1` or similar, even if I use `Run` keyword `If` and `Evaluate` instead of `set var`, I tried to convert to integer but nothing happens and I cannot convert it to integer or number. Any suggestions? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're simply wanting to increment `${COUNT}` if `${CELLVALUE}` equals `${EXPECTEDVALUE}`. That can be done pretty easily with [Set Variable if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If)

If you know that `${CELLVALUE}` and `${EXPECTEDVALUE}` are of the same internal type (eg: strings or ints), and you're using robot framework 2.9 or greater, you can write it like this:

```
${COUNT}=    Set variable if    $CELLVALUE == $EXPECTEDVALUE 
...   ${COUNT+1}    ${COUNT}
```

This assumes that `${COUNT}` is initialized to an integer value, which you can do by assigning it the value `${0}`

If you don't know the type, can't guarantee the type, or are using an older version of robot, you can use triple-quoted strings to coerce the values to strings:

```
${COUNT}=    Set variable if    '''${CELLVALUE}''' == '''${EXPECTEDVALUE}'''    
...    ${COUNT+1}    ${COUNT}
```

Of course, you could use Run Keyword and Return Status like in your example, and then compare the status. That seems like an unnecessary extra step, but it might make sense in your actual test.

The point being, you can use [Set variable if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If) and [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) to solve this problem.

---

Note 1: With [Set variable if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If), two values are provided. The first value is assigned if the expression is true, the second one is assigned if the value is false. The second value is the original variable, meaning it won't be changed. If you don't provide the second value, the variable will be set to `None`.

Note 2: Putting an expression inside curly braces (eg: `${COUNT+1}` is documented in rule 4 of [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax).

Note 3: Starting with robot framework 2.9, variables are available in the evaluation namespace with the simplified syntax `$varname`. So, the robot variable `${CELLVALUE}` can be used in python expressions as `$CELLVALUE`. This is documented in the section [Evaluating Expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions) in the BuiltIn library documentation.

Comment: Note 4: ${COUNT} needs to be initialized to an int type, e.g. ${COUNT}=    Set Variable    ${0} or you get a variable resolution error.